# ‘_timer’ {aka ‘struct timer_list’} has no member named ‘data’

Tags: linux, networking, driver

I am using Kali Kinux **4.19.0-kali5-amd64** and need drivers for [TL-WN822N V5](https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201805/20180514/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta.zip) [offered here](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/tl-wn822n/).

There are errors attempting to compile:

[image: errors]

Comment: I'm also getting the same error. Have you found any solution?

Comment: No did not find

Answer (score 2):

The official beta version of the driver only supports up to the 4.9.60 Linux kernel. You are on a newer version.

This [github repo](https://github.com/ZeeRooo/RTL8192EU) has a tested version that supports TL-WN822N V5.

- Download the repo, install the Linux kernel sources and headers.
- Build the module (`make`) and copy to /lib/modules/{your-kernel}/kernel/drivers. You can use `uname -r` to find {your-kernel}.
- Run `depmod -a` then `modprobe 8192eu` and `insmod 8192eu.ko`.

Looks like there is also another alternative to the driver above. This [seems also work](https://github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux).